# Finding intersection points between meshes

Tags: babylonjs

how to get all intersection points, while two different mesh collide/intersect?

`ex. mesh.intersectsMesh(anotherMesh)` it return bool.

In my case I need to find all intersection points.

Comment: Hi, did you resolve the issue? I am facing a similar issue so I was wandering whether you found any solution.

Comment: I handled it with bounding box method, find bigger bounding box from two of the mesh and use one mesh bounding box to find another mesh points(geometry) within it